# Convert whole .pem Certificate to hexadecimal

Tags: certificate, openssl

I want to convert a whole pem-Certificate in hexadecimal. I tried it with: 
`openssl x509 -modulus -noout < cert.pem| sed s/Modulus=/0x/` 
I'n not sure about it, if this is the right way to do. Am I?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Encode it as text or something else? At face vale doesn't look like a security question...might be better asked at SU?

Comment: I have to save certificates on a special place, where they must be in hex.
Yes. Might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a hexdump of the certificate, you could use the xxd command.

`xxd -p cert.pem` will give you a plain hexdump of the certificate.